# bitnami docker kafka: Invalid value for configuration message.max.bytes

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, bitnami, bitnami-kafka

I'm encountering an issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value  for configuration message.max.bytes: Not a number of type INT
```

when trying to run bitnami image kafka broker inside Docker. It has appeared when I had switched to Macbook Pro M3. On Intel Macbook Pro it had been working smoothly out of box. What should I do to make this Kafka instance work? I have installed Java via brew but it didn't help. My docker-compose file look like this:

```
services:
  kafka:
    image: &kafka-image bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - ${KAFKA_BROKER_PORT_1}:${KAFKA_BROKER_PORT_1}
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:${KAFKA_BROKER_PORT_1}
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://${KAFKA_BROKER_SERVER_1}:${KAFKA_BROKER_PORT_1}
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
      - KAFKA_CFG_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE=2097152
      - TEST_TOPIC_NAME=test
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_data:/bitnami/kafka
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "kafka-topics.sh", "--bootstrap-server=localhost:9092", "--list"]
      start_period: 15s
      interval: 10s

  # This service needs for setup kafka topics
  setup-kafka:
    image: *kafka-image
    working_dir: /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: |
      kafka-topics.sh --create --if-not-exists --topic test --replication-factor=1 --partitions=1 --bootstrap-server kafka:9092
```

I thought problem was in docker-compose file, but I also tried to run an instance from clear bitnami image. E.g

```
  kafka_1:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
```

But problem did not disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following env var to the environment section: `KAFKA_CFG_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=20000000`